# File Browser Navigation Menu broken

Tags: matrix

EE v2.5.0

Matrix 2.2.2.1

When I select ‘Add Image’ in a Matrix field, in the File Browser popup the navigation links are not correctly created and return a ‘404’, and the ‘Show files as’ select has no effect.

I'm not sure that this is a matrix problem as File Manager is a core component.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you include the native file browser as a stand-alone field?

Comment: Very good point; I set up a 'test' channel and fields, but when I try to add a new entry, the file field doesn't have an entry field, it just displays the instructions in the Add Entry form!

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what that last sentence means. Is this a new install? If so, make sure everything's been uploaded correctly.

Comment: What I mean is that, there is no input field for the file field that I added to the test channel, it only displays the instructions, no actual place to add images.

Comment: Is this a new install?

Comment: no, it was set up 2 years ago, by another developer, the client tells me that this problem has always existed though

Comment: Is the File module actually installed? Not just the fieldtype, but the module too?

Comment: Howdy - you have very old versions of EE and Matrix.  I suspect that upgrading will relieve much of this, actually.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: Hmmm, the File module was not installed, but I installed it, and no change.

Comment: Hi Lisa, I've upgraded EE and matrix, but now when I edit an entry and select '+ add image' the File Manager opens and momentarily displays the images, which promptly disappear.
'You have no files uploaded to this directory. Please take a look at the documentation, and then sync your directories.'
I tried syncing, but all it seems to have done is removed the images from the entries too!

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:
Firebug shows this-

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://w w w.DOMAIN.com/themes/third_party/matrix/styles/matrix.css?2.5.4"

matrix.css?2.5.4

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://w w w.DOMAIN.com/themes/third_party/matrix/scripts/matrix.js?2.5.4"

matrix.js?2.5.4

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://w w w.DOMAIN.com/themes/third_party/matrix/scripts/matrix_conf.js?2.5.4"

matrix...s?2.5.4

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://w w w.DOMAIN.com/themes/third_party/matrix/styles/matrix.css?2.5.4"

matrix.css?2.5.4

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://w w w.DOMAIN.com/themes/third_party/matrix/scripts/matrix_text.js?2.5.4"

matrix...s?2.5.4

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://w w w.DOMAIN.com/themes/third_party/matrix/scripts/matrix.js?2.5.4"

matrix.js?2.5.4

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://w w w.DOMAIN.com/themes/third_party/matrix/scripts/matrix_text.js?2.5.4"

matrix...s?2.5.4

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://w w w.DOMAIN.com/themes/third_party/matrix/scripts/matrix_conf.js?2.5.4"

matrix...s?2.5.4

ReferenceError: MatrixConf is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

<script type="text/javascript">MatrixConf.EE2 = true;

index....up_id=4 (line 1100)

ReferenceError: MatrixConf is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

<script type="text/javascript">MatrixConf.EE2 = true;
```

I would put images but for some reason stackexchange is asking me to have reputation 10. Total Absurd!

**Which means you have uploaded only 1st part to system and didnt upload second part to themes. It happen to me! Just upload correctly!**

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the error: 'The requested URL /C=content_publish&M=filemanager_actions&action=directory_contents&tbl_offset=15 was not found on this server.' is my error response.

Comment: Ok please look at this: http://boldminded.com/support/ticket/396 I hope it helps. Rate if it did ;) Your answer si at the bottom. Re-copy themes distributed folder.

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't think the client has the original install file

Comment: I tried re-copying the themes folder, but no luck.

Comment: Update EE to 2.6.1
Update matrix to 2.5.4

It will solve it